# How to change ActiveForm from another Class

Tags: c#

I would like to ask for help. I would like to achieve that in Form1 in the panel I open Form2 in which there is a button, when the user presses in the panel on Form1 opens Form3

Here I am in the Form1 code where the user presses the button that is in the window, and thus Form2 opens in the panel

```
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form activeForm;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OpenSlaveForm(Form podrizenyForm, object btnSender)
    {

        if (activeForm != null)
        {
            activeForm.Close();
        }
        activeForm = podrizenyForm;
        podrizenyForm.TopLevel = false;
        podrizenyForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        podrizenyForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.pnlMain.Controls.Add(podrizenyForm);
        this.pnlMain.Tag = podrizenyForm;
        podrizenyForm.BringToFront();
        podrizenyForm.Show();
        string nazev = podrizenyForm.Text.ToUpper();


    }

    private void btnForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenSlaveForm(new Forms.Form2(), sender);
    }
}
```

}

Here I am in Form2 and I try to open Form3 through the button in the Form1 panel

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.OpenSlaveForm(new Forms.Form3(), sender);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: 1-Never post your code as a picture. 2-Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: Yes, but not complete, you should provide a reproducible example, this code isn't reproducible, is missing a lot of code.

Comment: And what now? I made a new example

Comment: You are creating a *new* `Form1` instance inside `Form2` so the new form will be embedded in that new `Form1` instance (which you aren't showing, that's why you don't see anything). You need a *reference* to the current `Form1` instance inside `Form2`.

Comment: oh ... i understand. Thank you

Comment: and could you please advise me how to close in Form2 Panel and open Form3 in this Panel

I understood that it was enough to set frm.Show (); but that opens a whole new window for me and I don't want that.

Comment: I already have posted an answer with what you exactly need to do, have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new `Form1` instance when you press the button in `Form2`, that adds the new `Form3` to that new instance instead in the one you are seeing on the screen.

You need to pass a reference to the current `Form1` instance to `Form2`:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    Form1 mainInstance;

    //Add a new constructor which accepts a reference to Form1
    public Form2(Form1 MainInstance)
    {
        mainInstance = MainInstance;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Now use that instance to create Form3
        mainInstance.OpenSlaveForm(new Forms.Form3(), sender);
    }
}
```

Now, change the button call in `Form1`:

```
private void btnForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Use the new constructor in order to pass the current instance
    OpenSlaveForm(new Forms.Form2(this), sender);
}
```